# python download file from Synology FileStation API

Tags: python, api, http, nas, synology

I'm trying to write a python script to download files from Synology NAS API

url used:

```
http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Download&version=2&method=download&path=%2FPATH%2FTO%2FFILE&mode=download&sid=SID
```

Downloading files from the browser is Ok, so the URL with GET is working, with python I can only get a file with this content, even with status_code of request being 200 OK:

```
{"error":{"code":119},"success":false}
```

Methods tried in python:

```
download = requests.get(download_url, allow_redirects=True)
open('file.csv', 'wb').write(download.content)
```

and:

```
x = requests.get(download_url, stream = True)
with open("file.csv", "wb") as csv:
   for chunk in x.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
      if chunk:
         csv.write(chunk)
```

without success

Comment: Is the issue regarding the 119 error code, or others?

Answer (score 1):

When using requests to download file from Synology headers should include **Content-Type** and **Content-Disposition**:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'
}
```

and then append **_sid** to the URI:

```
/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Download&version=2&method=download&path=/sample.xlsx&mode=open&sid=yss5QiB17T8NI1940PEN104300&&_sid=yss5QiB17T8NI1940PEN104300
```

Of course, sid is variable.